# Selectively apply regex in python

Tags: python, regex

How do I selectively apply regex on a string such that all numbers get removed only if not surrounded by letters; similarly all special characters get removed only if not surrounded by letters/numbers-

Example
CBR3762E remains same(not CBRE) while 23 00 AM becomes "AM"

also,
GRS_WAIT-ZQDPAY5M remains same since there are letters surrounding the '_' and '-'.

Comment: Make your selector more precise? e.g. `(^|\s)\d+($|\s)` will only match sequences of numbers which are preceded and followed by whitespace (including newline) or the start / end of the string. There's also "lookbehind" and "lookahead" assertions which allow making more complex predicates without making the content part of the match, so it might be useful to use that in order to ensure the leading or trailing whitespace doesn't get removed, and thus not risk issues of overlapping matches. Although the overlapping matches could also be handled by matching on of whitespace-separated numbers.

Comment: You can use negative lookahead and lookbehind (https://regex101.com/r/fuHI6Y/1) to ensure there is not a specific character around the match. Does this suit your needs?

Comment: How do you define "special characters"? How would you handle `ABC 23 00 AM`?

Comment: No. `23 00 AM` should become '  AM'. Otherwise you are not just replacing numbers but also what is surrounding them. If you really mean to replace those also, then update your question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 0):

> *"How do I selectively apply regex on a string such that all numbers get removed only if not surrounded by letters ..."*

You could check the first and last character using *[str.isalpha](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha)*, and then replace all numbers with an empty value.

The regex pattern would be `\d+`, which will match all digits, 1 or more.

```py
string = '23 00 AM'
if not string[0].isalpha() or not string[-1].isalpha():
    string = re.sub(r'\d+', '', string)
```

Output

```
  AM
```

> *"... 23 00 AM becomes "AM" ..."*

In this case, just use the *[str.strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)* function to remove the trailing whitespace.

```py
string = re.sub(r'\d+', '', string).strip()
```

> *"... similarly all special characters get removed only if not surrounded by letters/numbers ..."*

You can use the same approach, check the first and last character using the *[str.isalnum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum)* function.

For the pattern, you can use a negated character class.

```
(?i)[^a-z\d]+
```

```py
if not string[0].isalnum() or not string[-1].isalnum():
    string = re.sub(r'(?i)[^a-z\d]+', '', string).strip()
```